# How to label x-axis in ggplot when using facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to change the x-axis on my plot with the code below. I named the desired labels on scale_x-discrete in orders corresponding to the legend to the right of the plot but they ended up messy. Corn appeared twice while Oat was missing for "Three-year", then Corn appeared twice again in "Four-year" with Alfalfa missing. Labels were mixed up for "Three-year" and "Four-year" too.

```html
data$rotation[data$Rot.trt %in% c("C2", "S2")]<-"TwoYear"
data$rotation[data$Rot.trt %in% c("C3", "S3", "O3")]<-"ThreeYear"
data$rotation[data$Rot.trt %in% c("C4", "S4", "O4", "A4")]<-"FourYear"

##plot, by rotation #scales = free_x X axis depends on facet
data$rotation <- factor(data$rotation, levels = c("TwoYear", "ThreeYear", "FourYear"))
ggplot(data, aes(Rot.Herb, kg.ha, fill=Crop))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_grid(~rotation, scales = "free_x", space="free_x")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")+
  ggtitle("Weed biomass by plot")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=30, face="bold", vjust=2))+
  xlab("Rotation systems and Herbicide regimes (L = Low herbicide regime, C = Conventional herbicide regime)")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Corn C", "Corn L", "Soybean C", "Soybean L", "Corn C", "Corn L", "Oat C", "Oat L", "Soybean C", "Soybean L", "Alfalfa C", "Alfalfa L", "Corn C", "Corn L", "Oat C", "Oat L", "Soybean C", "Soybean L"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  ylab("Weed dry weight")
```

Please find picture and data here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jb6gjznyw2q16mx/AADcNKiicqkoHxpFYIsaTgk9a?dl=0

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Please embed your image and a representative sample of the data.  Dropbox links don't usually stay valid for as long as SO questions. :)

Comment: I'd love to but I don't have enough points. :*(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `scale_x_discrete` you can map `Rot.Herb` values into your axis labels  using `mapvalues` from `plyr` package and then group on that. I'm not sure if I got the labels completely right, but something along those lines

```
...
library(plyr)
data$Rot.Herb.label <- mapvalues(data$Rot.Herb, 
          c('C2conv', 'C2low', 'S2conv', 'S2low', 'C3conv', 'C3low',
            'O3conv', 'O3low', 'S3conv', 'S3low', 'A4conv', 'A4low',
            'C4conv', 'C4low', 'O4conv', 'O4low', 'S4conv', 'S4low'),
          c("Corn C", "Corn L", "Soybean C", "Soybean L", 
            "Corn C", "Corn L", "Oat C", "Oat L", "Soybean C", 
            "Soybean L", "Alfalfa C", "Alfalfa L", "Corn C", "Corn L",
            "Oat C", "Oat L", "Soybean C", "Soybean L"))


ggplot(data, aes(Rot.Herb.label, kg.ha, fill=Crop))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_grid(~rotation, scales = "free_x", space="free_x")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")+
  ggtitle("Weed biomass by plot")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=30, face="bold", vjust=2))+
  xlab("Rotation systems and Herbicide regimes (L = Low herbicide regime, C = Conventional herbicide regime)")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  ylab("Weed dry weight")
...
```

That produces
[image]